# Optional whitespace character in this regular expression pattern

Tags: regex

I would like to read information from a configuration file that should be somewhat structured. However, I want to provide some leeway for personal preferences.

The file should include the name of the parameter, followed by an equals sign (with optional leading/trailing whitespaces), as well as the actual value to be assigned.

Example of a **valid** configuration file:

```
schedule = 60
schedule=60
schedule= 60
```

Example of an **invalid** configuration file:

```
schedule 60
schedule => 60
schedule: 60
```

I would like to find a match if the configuration file contains a recognized parameter with a properly assigned value, as shown in the example of the valid configuration file.

So far, I have only been able to come up with the following expression:

```
(?<=schedule\s=\s).*$
```

Unfortunately, this will only match the first line in the example of the valid configuration file. How could I make the whitespaces optional so that all three examples would be regarded as valid by the regular expression? Note that I am only interested in the right-hand side of the equals sign.

Comment: Use `schedule\s*=\s*\K.+` or `schedule\s*=\s*(.+)`. What is the programming language/tool?

Comment: This does indeed match all three valid cases. However, it will also match cases such as: `schedule == 60`, which is incorrect as the delimiter is not a single equals sign.

Comment: Then you need to make sure the `.*` is replaced with the exact pattern you need. Or at least that is start with a digit: `schedule\s*=\s*\K\d.*` / `schedule\s*=\s*([0-9].*)`. You may also use [Malay Shah's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53813916/3832970).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below regex:
^schedule\s*=\s*([0-9]+)

Also the value are grouped so Group-1 would contain only the value(60 in your case)

Comment: Thank you. This will solve my problem. I will mark your answer as the solution when the option becomes available.

Comment: Thanks @MihkelPajunen. Glad that it helped what you were looking for